# catch data error in informatica

Tags: shell, informatica

Actually, I have a shell script which calls the informatica workflow. but i want to add a functionality in script to catch the data error while processing of data in workflow if required, and give the error message on screen like (error is coming due to wrong data .please refer the logs). Currently log is generated but i am unable to show screen message by using shell script.

below is command to call the workflow

```
pmcmd startworkflow -sv CSA_DEV_INT -d Domain_CSADevelopment -u Administrator -p Administrator -f Sumit -wait wf_ERROR_LOG_TESTING
pwc_status=$?
```

but the value of `pwc_status` is coming as 0 whereas I processed the wrong data. and informatica logs catch the error.

Comment: Yes Marek..you are right. but is there any way to print the wrong data error by using shell script?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the `pmcmd` call itself is successful (i.e. the server is found, the user can be authenticated, the workflow starts) it will return 0, even if there are errors while processing data. Use the the `getworkflowdetails` or `gettaskdetails` commands of the `pmcmd` utility to obtain details related to the workflow execution.

For more information about these commands see the *Command Reference* - you can find it in the Informatica installation directory on your server or download from [Informatica My Support site](https://communities.informatica.com/) (you need to be a registered user).